# Making an Integer array inside Object class reference variable

Tags: java

If i try to make array of Object class in java, it works fine

```
Object[] o = new Integer[]{1,2,3};
    for(Object x : o)
        System.out.print(x);
```

Output is: 123

I found out that you can also do

```
Object o = new Integer[]{1,2,3};
```

It doesn't give compile fail. I want to know that can we iterate through the Integers in reference 'o' ?

Then i tried this

```
class A{ }

class B extends A{ }

class App{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        A a = new B[4];
    }
}
```

But her `A a = new B[4];` gives CF

Comment: what do you mean "you cannot do such thing with any other class"?

Comment: Every class in Java inherits from `Object` class. When you call `System.out.print` it calls the default `.toString()` method of the given object, which in this case would be `Integer.toString()`

Comment: @Abhijeet I've added the why it doesn't work for your A and B in my updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every single Object-type in Java inherits from the `Object` class.

So, basically: an `Integer` is an `Object`, which is why you can do this:

```
Object[] o = new Integer[]{1,2,3};
```

On the other hand, `Arrays` are `Objects`, too, meaning you can do this:

```
Object o = new Integer[]{1,2,3};
```

In the first example, the `Integers` are the `Objects`, in your second, the `Object` o is a reference to the `Array` of `Integers`

UPDATE: The reason between your `A` and `B` classes, you do have an Exception, is because even though each `B` is an `A`, the `Array` in which you store your `B`'s is not an `A`.

Answer (score 2):

Java arrays are covariant. Meaning that, You can use a Sub type in place of Type.

So if you have an array of "Type", you can actually fill that array with "SubType"'s. Well, any class in Java is a Subtype of Object. Hence no error in that case.

```
  Object o = new Integer[]{1,2,3};
```

> It doesn't give compile fail.

Again the same things, as Array is also an Object in the end, hence you are free to assign that to an Object.

> I want to know that can we iterate through the Integers in reference 'o' ?

By default, Object is not iterable. Where as Array object is.

So before you going to iterate, you have to cast it to type Array.

Update :

> But her A a = new B[4]; gives CF

Ofcourse that is not a valid declaration You should write

```
A[] a = new B[4];  // just to satisfy the compiler. At run time you are not allowed to store A's in it.
```

But if you are trying to achive the style

```
  Object o = new Integer[]{1,2,3};
```

No that won't work here and you can only write

```
 Object o =  new B[4];
```

That is because array is a sub type of `Object` class and not `A` class.

Comment: Don't write `A[] a = new B[4];` because `a` looks like an `A`-Array but throws a `ArrayStoreException` as soon as you try to add an Object of the Type `A`.

Comment: @devpuh You are true, just trying to demonstrate the covariance.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is possible is that an array is a subclass of Object. However, by storing the array in `o`, the program "forgets" the fact that `o` is holding an array. For that reason, you cannot iterate over `o`.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will only allow you to do things that it "knows" you can do to that particular class. Here's an analogy: you want to haul 1 metric ton of sand for a few miles. Would you request a "vehicle," or would you specifically request some kind of truck that you knew would be large enough to haul the sand? If you request a "vehicle of some kind," for all you know they might send you a Prius, which obviously wouldn't do you any good - a Prius can't haul 1 ton of sand. In this case, the compiler would "complain" that there's absolutely no guarantee that you'll be sent a vehicle that has the capacity to do what you want.

Types work that way, too - by default, it's perfectly valid to upcast the array to type `Object`, since *everything* in Java is a subtype of `Object`. But, from the compiler's perspective, there's absolutely guarantee that you can iterate over something of that type, so it won't let you do that.

Comment: the question is not about iteration.

Comment: @Stultuske *" I want to know that can we iterate through the Integers in reference 'o' ?*" How is that not asking about iteration?

Comment: his issue is with this: A a = new B[4]; gives CF